# Match all *.js files except for two (or more)

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a reg. expression to match all ***.js** files in my **/lib** directory except for (for example) **jquery.js** and **require.js**.

```
^(\/lib/)([^\/]*)$
```

the above only selects all the .js files inside the lib directory but I'm not sure where to define the exclude part.

```
/lib/jquery.js
/lib/handlebars.sj
/librequire.js
/lib.test.js
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this with regex? It would be a lot easier to filter out those two cases.

Comment: Use a negative lookahead.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I'm not really good at regex so I could really use an example in this case.

Comment: ColBeseder , I'd like to use this regex for r.js so it clears all the unnecessary scripts from build directory after the optimization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this regex<sup>*</sup> (if I understood you correctly):

```
\/lib\/(?!jquery|require).*\.js
```

It matches all `.js` files inside `/lib/` directory except `jquery.js` and `require.js`.

This is called [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), it's used when you want to match something *not* followed by something else.

Note that this regex does not match anything that start with `jquery` or `require` (after `/lib/`), if you want so, you can easily bound the wanted words.

<sup>* I don't think regex is your best approach for this problem</sup>

Comment: How does it exclude `jquery.js` and `require.js`?

Comment: This doesn't match `/lib/jquery foo.js`.

Comment: @Rawing `\b` will fix this if OP wants.

Comment: @MarounMaroun if you could just include in your answer that the regex does not match anything that start with jquery or require. Just to other looking know about this.

Comment: I have tested it on regex101.com and it was working perfectly but I couldn't make it work with r.js. Thanks for posting the solution though.

Comment: @Wracker It *does* match `/lib/r.js`, please elaborate more.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, your regex solution is working. It's just the **r.js** optimization script where the regex does not seem to work.

Comment: @Wracker I'll be glad to help if you edit your question or post another question with a full explanation of the problem. And you're more than welcome :)

Comment: @Maroun Maroun , that would be great - This is a separate 
post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898856/r-js-excluding-specific-list-of-files) I have created a while ago.

Comment: One more thing. Is it also possible to match all files that contains jquery or require words? Something like `\/lib\/(?!*jquery|require).*\.js` (not sure if this works) - to cover files like /lib/jquery-1.0.1.js and so on..