# r.js - excluding specific list of files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

**Hello evryone,**

I'm trying to find a way to make the **r.js** not to copy all the files form my **/lib/** directory except for (for example) **jquery.js** and **require.js**.

I'm using **fileExclusionRegExp** option to exclude all *.js files except for the above mentioned.

```
 fileExclusionRegExp: '\/lib\/(?!jquery|require).*\.js'
```

But after the optimization, I can still see that other files have been copied over too.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong ? Or is the regex incorrect?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is just a guess (because I don't know r.js at all), but shouldn't the regex match those files that you want to __exclude__?

Comment: yes it should list all files I want to exclude except those two..or whatever is specified..

Comment: Your regex matches the files you want to __include__. Try `/lib/(?:jquery|require)\.js` to match `jquery.js` and `require.js`.

Comment: well this regex doesn't seem to work at all..

Comment: Do you have only the  jquery.js and require.js in the lib directory? Because then you can just write `fileExclusionRegExp: '(?!jquery|require).*\.js'`. The `fileExclusionRegExp` only applies the regex to the directory and file names so not to the full path you you cannot write the `/lib/...` there...

Comment: nope, there are few more javascripts. I'd like to define which javascripts will not be copied over to the build directory.

Comment: I mean do you have another copy of the jquery.js or a require.js file somewhere else than the lib directly which you want to copy? Because if you only have them in the lib then the pattern without including the `lib` directory there: `fileExclusionRegExp: '(?!jquery|require).*\.js'` should work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've run into is that you are trying to make `fileExclusionRegExp` match the entire path of a file, but `r.js` uses it only to test against the base name of files. You can infer this from the description of the option and its default value. The [description](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L497) says:

```
//When the optimizer copies files from the source location to the
//destination directory, it will skip directories and files that start
//with a ".".
```

The default value is:

```
/^\./
```

If this were to be tested against a full path, it would not be able to exclude files that start with a period if they are in a subdirectory. We also find confirmation of this behavior in [this issue report](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/384).

If you have only one file named `require.js` and one file named `jquery.js`, then you can get by with this regexp:

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /^(?!jquery|require).*\.js$/
```

Otherwise, `fileExclusionRegExp` is not going to do it, and you should use a build step to clean your directory, as suggested by the author of RequireJS in the issue report I mention above.